# Dried condensed milk

Tags: condensed-milk

I want to make custard caramel. The recipe which I will follow requires condensed milk.
Now I have an opened refrigerated tin of condensed milk. Half of it is used. The other half is dried, though not expired.
So is it safe to use that? Also how can I melt the dried condensed milk?
PS: Dried in the sense that it has become little solid.

Comment: How long has the open can been in the refrigerator?

Comment: @GdD about 2-3 months

Comment: Then it's bad and you should throw it out @Oj16. The expiration date is for the **unopened** can, once opened you need to use it within a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GdD said in a comment, it's probably better to just toss it. Although I will say that sweetened condensed milk actually lasts 2-3 weeks if refrigerated properly. After several months though, it's not worth the risk. In the future, you can store an extra half can in the freezer for 2-3 months without issue instead.

That said, sweetened condensed milk is actually just milk that's been reduced with sugar until it's quite thick. You can make a substitute at home by blending together fresh and powdered milk and sugar. I've seen multiple recipes, but have to admit I haven't tried it personally. So you might still be able to make your custard without a run to the store. Good luck!